# replace pandas DataFrame value pattern

Tags: python, pandas

This is my current DataFrame using pandas, and it has some mixed type values in `order_number` column

```
       order_number             created_time  customer_id  driver_id 
153280        40487  2017-02-01 12:39:25.887         1413       96.0   
153281       118898  2017-02-01 10:52:38.822        51640     5382.0   
153282      "36968"  2017-02-02 20:54:43.141        49072     6851.0   
153283      "68383"   2017-02-02 19:01:08.52        28742     4479.0   
153284      "56261"  2017-02-01 06:09:53.245        31656        NaN
```

and I want to remove the quote mark from the order number so that the DataFrame would be like this:

```
       order_number             created_time  customer_id  driver_id 
153280        40487  2017-02-01 12:39:25.887         1413       96.0   
153281       118898  2017-02-01 10:52:38.822        51640     5382.0   
153282        36968  2017-02-02 20:54:43.141        49072     6851.0   
153283        68383   2017-02-02 19:01:08.52        28742     4479.0   
153284        56261  2017-02-01 06:09:53.245        31656        NaN
```

I already tried to use replace method like below but it didn't work.

```
df['order_number'].replace('""','')
```

Can anyone help?
Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['order_number'] = df['order_number'].str.strip('"').astype(float)
```

Or add parameter `regex=True` for replace `substring`s:

```
df['order_number'] = df['order_number'].replace('"','', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Last convert values to `float`s.